# How to read a response request json instagram

Tags: instagram

Someone have a program to read json response of the request instagram
The request is :https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/43930738/media/recent/?&client_id=603c5124d6d94dfdbc9d6b0886134367&min_timestamp=1393286400
with vb6

Answer (score 0):

HAve a look at Json.Net.

Here's an article on the plugin: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NuGetPackageOfTheWeek4DeserializingJSONWithJsonNET.aspx